# How to show that $\sqrt[4]{13}$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}_{13}(\sqrt[4]{26})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, extension-field, p-adic-number-theory

**Approach**

- I was able to show that $[\mathbb{Q}_{13}(\sqrt[4]{26}):\mathbb{Q}_{13}] = 4$ since $x^4 - 26$ in an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}_{13}[x]$ (this can be shown by using Eisenstein's Criterion and the Gaussian Lemma). Therefore, a basis of $\mathbb{Q}_{13}(\sqrt[4]{26})$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space is $$ (1, \sqrt[4]{26}, \sqrt{26}, \sqrt[4]{26^3}).$$
- If $\sqrt[4]{13}$ would be in $\mathbb{Q}_{13}(\sqrt[4]{26})$, then there would be coefficients $c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3 \in \mathbb{Q}_{13}$ such that $$(\sum_{k=0}^4 c_k \sqrt[4]{26}^k)^4 = 13. $$
  However, getting a contradiction out of this equation seems to be super complicated.

Could you please help me with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: That the root of your degree $4$ polynomial has valuation $1/4$ implies it is irreducible. Your extension is fully determined by its uniformizer $\sqrt[4]{2}\sqrt[4]{13} $ and residue field $\Bbb{F}_{13}$, then it suffices to find if $\sqrt[4]{2} $ is in $\Bbb{F}_{13}$ (in which case Hensel lemma implies it is in $\Bbb{Z}_{13}$)

Comment: @reuns: Could you explain to me how $\sqrt[4]{26}$ having valuation $1/4$ show that the polynomial is irreducible? For me, it is unclear how the valuation plays a role here. And is a uniformizer not an element which has valuation $1$? I think that the valuation of $\sqrt[4]{2} \sqrt[4]{13}$ has valuation $1/4$. And could you elaborate how $\sqrt[4]{2}$ plays a role with the residue field? I also do not understand all of these things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\pi_K$ an uniformizer, $v(p) = 1,v(\pi_K) = 1/e$ and the residue field $O_K/(\pi_K) = F_{p^f} = \sum_{j=0}^{f-1} \zeta_{p^f-1}^j F_p$ then $O_K = \sum_{m=0}^{e-1} \sum_{j=0}^{f-1} \zeta_{p^f-1}^j \pi_K^m Z_p$ so $[O_K:Z_p] = e f$.

Here $K = Q_p[a], a= 2^{1/4} 13^{1/4}, v(a)=1/4, e \ge 4$, since $a$ is the root of a polynomial of degree $4$ it means $ef \le 4,\pi_K = a, e=4,f = 1$ and $13^{1/4} \in O_K$ iff $2^{1/4} \in O_K$ iff (as $x^4-2\bmod p$ is separable, Hensel lemma) $2^{1/4} \in O_K/(\pi_K)=F_p$.

Comment: Kinda telegraphic, but anything I could add would be unnecessary embellishment. Plus one.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but why exactly is $v(2^{1/4}) = 0$? I only know $v(2^{1/4}) = \frac{1}{n} v(N_{K/\mathbb{Q}_{13}}(2^{1/4}))$ where $n$ is the degree of the extension. To compute that, I need to know the degree and a basis of $K$ as a $\mathbb{Q}_{13}$-vector space. The other thing I could think of is that $2^{1/4}$ is not divisible by $13$. But I have no convincing argument to show that. Could you please help me with this one?

Comment: @Diglett $v(2) = 4 v(2^{1/4})$ and $2$ is coprime with $p=13$, its $p$-adic valuation is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $2^{(13^2-1)/4}=(2^6)^7$ is congruent to $-1$ mod $13$, thus $2$ is not a fourth root in a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{F}_{13}$.

Therefore, $X^4-2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{13}$, thus in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ thus in $\mathbb{Q}_{13}$.

So $K=\mathbb{Q}_{13}[X]/(X^4-2)=\mathbb{Q}_{13}(2^{1/4})$ is a field with dimension $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}_{13}$.

So it is enough to prove that ${\sqrt{13}} \notin K$.

Now, if $\sqrt{13} \in K$, there are $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}_{13}$ such that $(a+b2^{1/4}+c2^{2/4}+d2^{3/4})^2=13$.

The equations are rewritten as $a^2+4bd+c^2=13$, $2ac+b^2+2d^2=0$, $4dc+2ab=0$, $2ad+2bc=0$.

Thus $ab=-2cd$, $ad=-bc$, $2ac+b^2+d^2=0$, $a^2+4bd+c^2=13$.

Assume $a=0$, then $c=0$ or $d=0$ and $b=0$ or $c=0$. If $c=0$, then $b^2+d^2=0$ and $4bd=13$, which is impossible because the $13$-adic valuations of $b$ and $d$ must both be the same and have an odd sum.

So if $a=0$, then $c \neq 0$, thus $b=d=0$, therefore $2c^2=13$, impossible.

So $a \neq 0$, thus $b=-2cd/a$, thus $d=-bc/a=2c^2d/a^2$, hence $d=0$ or $(c/a)^2=1/2$. The latter is impossible, because $2$ is not a square root mod $13$ (and $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ is integrally closed and surjects to $\mathbb{F}_{13}$), thus $b=d=0$, thus $2ac=0$, thus $c=0$, thus $a^2=13$, impossible.

So $\sqrt{13} \notin K$.

Thus there is no field extension of $\mathbb{Q}_{13}$ with dimension $4$ containing $2^{1/4}$ and $13^{1/2}$, let alone $26^{1/4}$ and $13^{1/4}$.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Could you please elaborate your first argument? I don't quite understand that. It probably has something to do with the fact that the mulplicative group of a quadratic extension of the finite field with 13 elements has $13^2-1$ elements, right?

Comment: Let $F$ be any quadratic extension of $\mathbb{13}$, so $|F|=169$. Assume $2$ is a fourth power in $F$. So there exists some $a \in F$ such that $2=a^4$. Thus, in $F^*$, $2^{42}=2^{168/4}=a^{168}=1$, because $F^*$ is a group with order $168$. Therefore, $2^{42}=1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{13}$. Now, $2^{42}=(2^6)^7$, and $2^6=-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{13}$, thus $2^{42}=(-1)^7=-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{13}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, I see what you did! I was able to understand your explanation. So in the same way, a cubic extension of the finite field is not possible. Is there any reason why you did not check it? Maybe it is not necessary and I don't know that.

Comment: I was trying to determine the dimension over $\mathbb{Q}_{13}$ of $\mathbb{Q}_{13}(2^{1/4})$. It is the same as the degree of the minimal polynomial $\pi$ of $2^{1/4}$ over $\mathbb{Q}_{13}$. Now, obviously, $\pi|X^4-2$. Since $X^4-2$ has no root in $\mathbb{Q}_{13}$, if the polynomial is reducible, it can be written as $(X^2+aX+b)(X^2+cX+d)$, $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}_{13}$. Then, in the quadratic extension $F=\mathbb{F}_{13}[T]/(T^2+aT+b)$, the class of $T$ is a zero of $X^4-2$, thus there is a fourth root of $2$ in $F$, which we proved was impossible.